# check what a java set of multiple strings contains

Tags: java, string, set

I have a set of the following form, with each element consisting of two numbers separated by space:

```
element1: 5 8
element2: 3 2
element3: 7 5
.....
```

How can I get the second number comprising the element (8,2,5) if I have the first number of the element (e.g. 5,3,7 respectively)?

```
 import java.util.*; 

 Set set = new HashSet();

try{
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;



while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   { 
set.add(strLine);
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean by checking if a number exists?

Comment: Iterate through the Set elements and check. What have you tried?

Comment: Set as in `java.util.Set`?

Comment: is there a way to do it without iteration, solely with set.contains?

Comment: Please post **code**, English has far too many ambiguities to determine what you're asking (e.g. your post is open to interpretation). In what way does the second number constitute a number? How is each element stored in the set?

Comment: it's a HashSet, have added code to show you how I populate it

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you are trying to do using only set.contains.

The new Collections Streaming API in Java 8 would allow you to do it, or you can loop over the values in the set, or you can build a Map.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little ambiguous 
If you want 2nd number comprising the element (8,2,5) , provided you have the first number of the element (e.g. 5,3,7 respectively)?

- Means a couple of things

  1. You have First numer as unique? - then store it as key value pair - Key (First#) Value(second#)
  2. You have A combination Unique? meaning `"element1+5"` can be key? - still [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) works
  3. You need to be able to pick Elements are random indexes say 1st 4th and 5th First element? You should have a custom data structure,
     modified [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) or [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) or [LInkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) , parse to find if Key
     exists if yes add value to a [Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) or [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) and then return populated array once complete.